# Return a string / pass by reference

Tags: c++, string, arduino, pass-by-reference

I am writing some C++ code for an Arduino board which has some hardware attached. In various places in the code I need to construct a string with values of the various attached hardware and send it over serial as part of a command. As it needs to be part of a very specific command sent over serial I construct it first and send it when the entire command is ready.

At the moment I am doing it via the function below

```
'String constructDataString ()
 {
    // Set up data to transmit
    String dataStr = String(var1);                          
    dataStr += ",";
    dataStr += String(var2);
    dataStr += ",";
    dataStr += String(var3);        
    dataStr += ",";
    dataStr += String(var4);    
    dataStr += ",";
    dataStr += String(var5);                            

    return dataStr;
 }'
```

I then call it with

```
String dataString = constructDataString ();
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do this by declaring a string in main and then passing it to the function by reference and allowing the function to modify it directly. I have tried this a few ways but I am having trouble getting it to work. I tried something like below but not that familiar with doing this so I was hoping someone might be able to help.

Prototype

```
void constructDataString (String* extString)
```

Call from main

```
String dataString =””;
String* dataStringPtr = & dataString;
constructDataString (dataStringPtr);
```

Function

```
void constructDataString (String* extString)
{
 // Set up data to transmit
    extString = String(var1);                           
    extString += ",";
    extString += String(var2);                                  
    extString += ",";
    extString += String(var3);      
    extString += ",";
    extString += String(var4);  
    extString += ",";
    extString += String(var5);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can. However in the body of `constructDataString`, you need to use `*extString` instead of `extString` to dereference the pointer.
Otherwise, you can use a reference in C++.

With the reference, the code would be:

```
void constructDataString (String& extString)
{
 // Set up data to transmit
    extString = String(var1);                           
    extString += ",";
    extString += String(var2);                                  
    extString += ",";
    extString += String(var3);      
    extString += ",";
    extString += String(var4);  
    extString += ",";
    extString += String(var5);
}
```

and you use it as follows:

```
String dataString =””;
constructDataString (dataString);
```

Comment: Hi Cantfindname, thank you very much, that has fixed it. I have been writing a lot of non c++ code lately so I had completely forgotten that part. I also generally avoid references in case of null parameters. I was wondering do you know if it is more efficient to do it the second way so that I am not passing strings on the stack?

Comment: Thanks Raw, just a typo on here :D

Comment: As far as I know, the references are mostly syntactic sugar in C++, so, after compiling, both ways would be exactly the same, and you will only push a pointer in the stack

Comment: Sorry Cantfindname I actually meant between the old way of doing it where I return a string and pass nothing and the new way where I just pass the pointer

Comment: Ah i see, yes it is more efficient, because when returning a string, it is copied, while with the pointer you write directly on its intended memory

Comment: Thanks dude, I appreciate you taking the time, have a great day :)